# What's a powerful file Watcher for windows?

Tags: windows

With the advent of downloading audio/video/ebook files from torrent and other means, I wonder if there are any powerful file watcher app out there that detects, filters, execute rule engine and determine which action needs to be executed to every detected files.

For e.g put tv series in a folder, clean up file name using regex. move audio files and import into itunes. etc.

I know I can write this kind of simple app myself, but just wondering if there's already exactly the same app out there that does the same thing. Extra point if it had a strong community behind it sharing rules and action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Belvedere](http://lifehacker.com/341950/belvedere-automates-your-self+cleaning-pc) is another tool you might want to have a look at. Haven't tried it myself though and maybe not as versatile as you want.

Comment: This app seems to fit exactly my criteria and the fact it's under GNU is awesome. I am downloading it now.

The only downside is this comment written on the website: "it may have a few bugs here and there (it won't accidentally go deleting all the files on your computer by any means, but I probably wouldn't point it at your most important folders right away"

Hopefully if there was a bug, it's a reproduceable one and behave consistently.

Comment: As to running external programs the tool is pretty primitive but I was able to run a CMD batch file with the "Open" action.
On problem is that it would run the same CMD over and over and there's no option to set it to run only once, e.g. on file creation. I had to work around with additional logic in my batch file so that it won't run multiple instances.

Answer (score 2):

**Luba Filewatcher** is freeware and a nice solution. You can [download](http://www.bajak.net/Content/Data/Filewatcher.zip) it or check out our [website](http://www.bajak.net/#References-Page) for more information. There is a short video with a example with typescript.
It watches for file changes inside a specified folder.

[image]

Comment: It is now open-source. http://sourceforge.net/projects/luba-filewatcher/

Answer (score 1):

[Directory Monitor](http://directorymonitor.com)

Based on your requirements it has a scripting facility so you can use batch, powershell, Node etc. to react to changes and pattern based inclusion/exclusions. There are a number of plugins to for simple tasks as well such as emailing, writing to a database and so forth.

[image: Screenshot]

DISCLAIMER: I am the developer of this product.

Answer (score 0):

[**DiskBoss**](http://www.diskboss.com/) is such a program. One of its features is a "[File System Change Monitor](http://www.diskboss.com/disk_change_monitor.html)". It can detect file changes that match rule and take action for these files.

[image]

Comment: It seems like an awesome product, but the price are much to steep.